# How to make cylinder and cube parts disappear in real time in unity3D？

Tags: unity-game-engine

there is a problem in the development process,I have a constantly moving cylinder, and when it overlaps with the cube, I want the overlapping part on the cube to disappear.Is there any way to accomplish this task ?Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You can probably do it with a [stencil shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/SL-Stencil.html). You should also specify if you're using a render pipeline as that influences the answers you can get.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice, I'll try it soon.